# Cannot access S3 from Laravel9 on Fargate

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, aws-fargate

### Environment

- `Laravel Framework 9.42.2`
- `"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^3.10"`

Fargate is built in `ap-northeast-1`

The following is the method (`app/Models/Image.php`) of the part where the problem is occurring.

```php
/**
 * S3に画像ファイルをアップロード
 *
 * @param object $image
 * @param string $uuid
 * @return bool|string
 */
public function uploadImageToS3(object $image, string $uuid): bool|string
{
　　// false is substituted on this line
    $uploaded_path = Storage::disk('s3')->putFileAs($this->post_image_dir, $image, $uuid.'.jpg');

    if (!$uploaded_path) {
        throw new Exception('S3 Put Error.');
    }

    return $uploaded_path;
}
```

Besides the above code, all other processes using `Storage::disk('s3')` return `false`.

### Specifics of the issue

I created an IAM user with access rights to the S3 bucket in AWS and put the following settings in `.env`.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXX
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXX
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=XXXXX
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false
```

I ran this code in my local environment (docker-compose) and it uploaded successfully.

However, when I ran this Docker Image with Fargate, an error occurred.
The `Storage::disk('s3')` process returns false, so I am thinking that either the connection to S3 is not working or it is a disk driver issue.

I also set the exact same `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, but when I check the date of last use of IAM User, it seems that it is not authenticated.

Other operations, such as `delete()`, `get()`, etc., are not performed correctly as well.

Is there a solution to the above error?

Or is there a way to log the cause of these errors?

Please let us know if you need any other information. I will add it.

### Tried

- Checking environment variables

  - Verified that environment variables were set correctly using `ECS Exec`
- Use another IAM User, S3 Bucket
- Confirmation of IAM permissions

  - Since it was working in the local environment, the authorization is considered appropriate.
- Update composer package

  - RUN: `composer update`
- Clear Cache

  - RUN: `php artisan config:clear`, `composer dump-autoload`, `php artisan env` on ECS

### PS

Configuration in `config/filesystems.php` as follows

```php
        's3' => [
            // Omitted
            'throw' => true, // Changed from false to true
        ],
```

This resulted in the following log output.

```
Aws\S3\Exception\PermanentRedirectException: 
Encountered a permanent redirect while requesting  https://s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/{BACKET_NAME}/{PATH}/{UUID}.jpg.
Are you sure you are using the correct region for this bucket? in /var/www/html/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/S3/PermanentRedirectMiddleware.php:49
```

The problem I see in this log is that the S3 endpoint is in the Tokyo (`ap-northeast-1`) region.
S3 is located in Virginia (`us-east-1`) and is configured in `.env` as follows.

```
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
```

A bucket was created in the Tokyo region for testing.
Then, I granted access rights to the created bucket to the IAM policy of the IAM user currently in use, and changed `AWS_BUCKET` in Laravel.
Then I was able to upload the file successfully.

However, this does not solve the root problem.

Why is the URI not set correctly only in Fargate?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html), it seems `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` are readonly environnement variables on ECS.

###### I suggest you to review the way you manage your container credentials.

You are currently trying to inject the credentials from your user into your application container. (This might sounds as a bad practice, as a company, your departure would break the application)
On AWS, your container should have a related role. Roles are kind of virtual users representing ressources. You can attach a policy on this role that would allow it to write on S3.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I intend to use AWS Secrets Manager during actual operation.
We also tried setting up IAM Role but this was not a solution.
As stated in the PS, it is not an application permissions issue, but rather an environment variable not being properly referenced in certain environments.
Is it possible for Fargate to unintentionally overwrite Laravel environment variables?